# Flexslider 2, how to load with (document).ready function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider, document-ready

I use the WooThemes Flexslider 2 plugin in my WordPress framework. 
Here is the code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#flexslider-<?php echo $postid; ?>').flexslider({
        smoothHeight:   true,
        slideshow:      false,
        start: function(slider) { 
            slider.container.click(function(e) { 
                if(slider.animating) { 
                    // action
                } else {
                    slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget('next'));
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The script works well with **"$(window).load(function() {"**
If I change the **"$(window).load(function() {"** to **"$(document).ready(function(){"** the slider doesn't work. In Safari the script loads successful, but doesn't get the current image height. How to make this script to work with **"$(document).ready(function(){"** on all browsers ? 
Thanks

Comment: `The script works well with "$(window).load(function() {"` then why do you want to change that to `document.ready`..

Comment: because with "$(window).load(function() {" user cannot use the slider after all other script is 100% loaded and it loads the last. With "$(document).ready(function(){" the slider loads at the same time with all other scripts. Thats the power od jquery.

Comment: another reason not to use `$(window).load(function() {` is that it conflicts with mediaelement in IOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an interval function which looks at the first image within your `$('#flexslider-<?php echo $postid; ?>')` element. Once it has finished loading, call the flexslider function.

This is to give you a hint, not tested:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var firstImage = $('#flexslider-<?php echo $postid; ?>').find('img').filter(':first'),
        checkforloaded = setInterval(function() {
            var image = firstImage.get(0);
            if (image.complete || image.readyState == 'complete' || image.readyState == 4) {
                clearInterval(checkforloaded);
                $('#flexslider-<?php echo $postid; ?>').flexslider({
                    // your options
                });
            }

        }, 20);

});
```

Comment: This is a workaround for an unresolved mediaelement issue: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/916